# Eclipse Add Project1 as dependent and auto import its dependents

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to get used to Eclipse/Java but am more familiar with MS VisualStudio. Lets say I have Java Library (Project1) which has some dependencies on jar files via `Properties->Java Build Path->Libraries` (eg: AWS SDK, gson, swagger, etc). Now if I have Project2 and set a project dependency for Project2 to Project1 via `Properties->Java Build Path->Project`, I would hope that Project1 dependents would also be included for Project2. I dont see that happening or I am missing a step. I have been googling but I don't see any tutorial/documentation discussing 2 levels of dependents. I see that the Project1 jar is being referenced but what about the dependents for Project1? I am receiving an error such as:

> The type XXXX cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from
>   required .class files XXXX

Answer (score 2):

I strongly suggest using **Maven**, which is a great and easy to use dependency manager.
Probably your eclipse already comes shipped with it, all you have to do is:

Do this for both projects:

Right click both projects, go to `Configure -> Convert to Maven Project`.

Create a **group id**,**artirfact id** and specify the **version** for your projects.

It will generate a **pom.xml** file in the root of your project.
Something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>

</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.6</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

You can add dependencies for your projects just by adding a **dependency** tag.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>yourGroup</groupId>
        <artifactId>yourProject</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

After that just right click your projects go to

`Run -> Run Configurations -> Maven Clean`

`Run -> Run Configurations -> Maven Install`

and it will automatically download and install your dependencies for you.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at Maven or a tool like this (Gradle, Ivy...) to handle your dependencies.

Relying on Eclipse for defining your build process (and dependencies) is a bad idea for long term projects.

Answer (score 0):

This depends a little, on your project.

In case it is just a Java project, then it is better to use a build tool like [Ant](http://ant.apache.org) with Ivy, [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/) or [Gradle](http://gradle.org/). As these contain the dependencies and other configuration details. Eclipse Mars (v4.5.1) comes with build in support for all these build tools.

In case it is an Eclipse Plug-in which you are developing, then you can configure it in Eclipse. And then store the configuration files, with the source code in the code repository.